# How to set the parameter 'underRelaxation' to a coupled equation?

Tags: fipy

I know that we can set the parameter 'underRelaxation' if we use 'sweep' to solve the equation.
eg:

`xVelocity_eq.sweep(dt=dt, underRelaxation = 0.5)`

But how to set this parameter to coupled equation.
eg:

`coupled_eq = xVelocity_eq & yVelocity_eq & zVelocity`

`coupled_eq.sweep(dt=dt,underRelaxation = ?)`

I have tried set underRelaxtion = 0.5 and set underRelaxation as a array like following code:

`relaxation = np.zeros(len(self.yVelocity) + len(self.zVelocity) + len(self.xVelocity))`
`relaxation[:] = velocityRelaxation`

`coupled_eq.sweep(dt=dt,underRelaxation = relaxation)`

However, it does not work correctly with an IndexError(indices out of range).If i do not set the underRelaxation, the error will not appear and the codes can run.

`File "C:\Program Files\Itasca\PFC500\exe64\python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\terms\term.py", line 237, in sweep`
`solver._applyUnderRelaxation(underRelaxation=underRelaxation)`

`File "C:\Program Files\Itasca\PFC500\exe64\python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\solvers\solver.py", line 133, in _applyUnderRelaxation`
`self.matrix.putDiagonal(self.matrix.takeDiagonal() / underRelaxation)`

`File "C:\Program Files\Itasca\PFC500\exe64\python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\matrices\pysparseMatrix.py", line 223, in putDiagonal`
`self.put(vector, ids, ids)`

`File "C:\Program Files\Itasca\PFC500\exe64\python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\matrices\offsetSparseMatrix.py", line 55, in put SparseMatrix.put(self, vector, id1 + self.mesh.numberOfCells * self.equationIndex, id2 + self.mesh.numberOfCells * self.varIndex)`

`File "C:\Program Files\Itasca\PFC500\exe64\python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\matrices\pysparseMatrix.py", line 198, in put self.matrix.put(vector, id1, id2)`

`IndexError: indices out of range`

Answer (score 1):

The `underRelaxation` argument takes a single float value greater than 0 up to 1. Setting the `underRelaxation=0.9` works fine in this example.

```
import numpy as np
from fipy import (
    CellVariable,
    TransientTerm,
    DiffusionTerm,
    Grid1D,
)

nx = 10

mesh = Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=1.0)

var_a = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=1.0)
var_b = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=0.0)

eqn_a = TransientTerm(var=var_a) == DiffusionTerm(var=var_a)
eqn_b = TransientTerm(var=var_b) == DiffusionTerm(var=var_b)

eqn = eqn_a & eqn_b

#underRelaxation = np.arange(nx * 2) / nx / 4. + 0.1
underRelaxation = 0.9

eqn.sweep(dt=1., underRelaxation=underRelaxation)
```

It seems that the `underRelaxation` argument can also be an array of the same length as the diagonal of the matrix (`2 * nx` in this case) although this may never have been how it was intended to be used. Anyway, `underRelaxation = np.arange(nx * 2) / nx / 4. + 0.1` works as well.

Comment: Thank you for your patient reply. I tried again, it works fine when I program in jupyter. But it does not work when I program in PFC (a software which include Python console). Maybe the problem is with the software.

Comment: Interesting. I can't imagine why the environment would matter just for this one parameter. Did you install FiPy in PFC or is it included as part of the package? If the latter, perhaps they provide an old version?